# How to properly test the proportions for multiple response (a.k.a. 'check all that apply') question with two possible answers?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-response

Suppose I have a survey and for the sake of simplicity let us suppose that I have asked a question: "What motivates you to work more efficiently?".
Now, if the possible answers were 'Money.', 'Social status.' or 'Both.', how can I test properly whether money or social status is more important and check, whether this discovery is statistically significant? Should the approach to such problem depend on the sample size?

I have seen similar questions with slightly different scope, hence I ask here separately. Thank you for your help!